# How does querying a hyperledger peer work?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Say a peer on my hyperledger network fails and is brought up again. It's behind, and doesn't contain the current ledger.

If my application queries that peer, it will have stale information.

Is it safe to assume that a peer will know if it is not up to date with the rest of the network, and not provide results to queries while it hasn't caught up?

Answer (score 1):

Extra verification for "if ledger is up-to-date" with thousands transactions per second can lead to additional load on the server. Taking into account that Node alone cannot guarantee if it works with the highest block (Network outage?) and has to send requests to other members - it can be potential bottleneck.

The was relevant discussion in this tread:
https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/761

> You would still need to worry about omission type errors (e.g. a VP
>   not returning the state from the most relevant block but rather some
>   past valid block). For that, I suppose we still need a "strong read"
>   type mechanism, but perhaps the validation of what constitutes "the
>   most recent block" is cheaper than returning the value itself...TBD.
>   One optimization that comes to mind might be the fact that the most
>   recent block isn't something specific to any one transaction or state,
>   so we might be able to piggy back multiple "strong read" confirmations
>   on one mechanism for verifying block height.

I saw that "strong read" was mentioned in several other threads and it possible that this approach will be selected as a solution.